# Creating a (tensor) network using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, node-connections, tensor, tikz-node

I am trying to draw a very simple network diagram. My code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, shape=circle] (v0) at (0,0) {$v_0$};
    \node[draw, shape=circle] (v1) at (1,0) {$v_1$};
    \node[rectangle,minimum width=6em,draw] (v3) at (0.5,-1) {$v_3$};
    \draw [thick] (v0) -- (v1)
    (v0) -- (v3)
    (v1) -- (v3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces the following figure:
[image]

I want the lines from the upper two nodes to go straight down towards the edge of the rectangle. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, it is :-):

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, shape=circle] (v0) at (0,0) {$v_0$};
    \node[draw, shape=circle] (v1) at (1,0) {$v_1$};
    \node[rectangle,minimum width=6em,draw] (v3) at (0.5,-1) {$v_3$};
    \draw [thick] (v0) -- (v1)
    (v0) -- (v0 |-  v3.north) % <-- changed coordinates
    (v1) -- (v1 |- v3.north); % <-- changed coordinates
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`|-` means that lines go first "verticaly" and than "horzontaly"  .... `(v0 |-  v3.north)` determine coordinate in intersection of  vertical lines through `v0.center` and horizontal line through `v3.north`.

Comment: Wow, that IS easy! Thank you very much for the quick and thorough help!!

Comment: Your are welcome! Happy TeXing!